# Why are two h5py files different in size when content is the same?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, h5py

I'm very puzzled at the moment and I'm hoping perhaps someone here can help me.

I have a h5py file provided to me online. I know very little details and I have been reverse engineering how this h5py file is created. It consists out of almost 200k datasets with (x, 768) shape whereby x is different per dataset.

I managed to reverse engineer how this file is created and have a near identical h5py file. I say near identical because the original h5py file is 3.6G and mine is 3.8G but they have the same amount of datasets with the same names, shapes and data type. How come the size is different when the files same the same?

Please let me know if I need to provide more details or some code. I'm not sure if I'm clear in explaining what I mean.

Comment: Check the file and dataset attributes, especially chunked storage,  compression and filters. Also, there are multiple ways to create HDF5 files, so the original file may NOT have been created with `h5py`. Ideally there is a root level attribute with source info. Note: You don't need to write any code to get attributes. You can access them with **HDFView** utility from The HDF Group.

Comment: `HDF5` files are not tightly packed; there's a lot of 'database' like baggage that allows them to grow and change.  So matching at the 3.6G versus 3.8G level strikes me as a pretty good achievement.  I suppose you are concerned because it suggests that your reverse engineering isn't perfect.

Comment: @kcw78 I compared the names, dtype and shape and they all are 100% identical.But I will look more into chunked storage, compression and filters. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @hpaulj You are right, I am afraid of that. Logically I would say if the names, amount of datasets and the shapes of all the datasets are identical but one is bigger than the other HDF5 file it would indicate that the data inside the arrays of the datasets are somehow bigger right?